# Delete old react build files in S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-deployment, aws-codebuild

I am deploying my react app in AWS S3 using AWS code build and caching through AWS CloudFront, But the bucket size is increased to more than **10GB** within a month due to frequent deployment.

I tried to delete old build files while deploying but it is causing issues to users who has the old code cached in their browser. As the old files trying to get the previous version build but those are deleted, So it throws 404.

I tried to set no-cache for index.html file but that does not resolve this issue.

Does anyone face this issue?

Answer (score 1):

@Nilanth here is what I do for the similar case:

My stack is also a React app (not so business critical) (it is used to offer article selection possibility for main content management flow..)  app is build via CodeCommit - Codebuild to s3 Bucket using CodePipeline & buildspec.yml file. Build it triggered by commit of the repository. I faced a similar problem, that Cloudfront didn't "offer" the newest JS files for the browser (html) so it started to feel like Cache-issue.

I make pretty good solution like this:

1. Update Cloudfront Cache settings (edit behaviour, set to use "Use legacy cache settings") and set min / max TTLs to 0. (this helps for cache, so user should get newest versions immediately)
2. For JS / CSS file issue, I add "aws cli remove command" lines to buildspec.yml file like:

- aws s3 rm s3://<s3_bucket>/static/js/ --recursive
- aws s3 rm s3://<s3_bucket>/static/css/ --recursive

Set those as pre_build commands
Note: See that by removing JS files your application can not be used before new ones are offered again from folders /js & /css. I your application is business critical then u could think beyond this, since there will be 30 - 60s time that app can not be used. And what if build fails, then there is no js/css assets at all, well then you can trigger old build from Codebuild. This will require some effort to do business critical app's Devops work here..

3. To allow "remove" executions to S3 Bucket, you need to give Codebuild additional permissions. Go to build projects,  see the environment's service role. Then go to IAM / roles / pick up the correct role name, and give more S3 permissions, e.g. AmazonS3FullAccess, its enough for sure..

I am not sure, that this is 99% correct solution from Cloudfront side, but it seems to avoid caching-problem and also the bucket size stays small.

-MM

Comment: Great answer. I got this working using a policy with only `s3:ListBucket` and `s3:DeleteObject`, limited to a specific S3 bucket and path.

Answer (score 0):

There are many elements there that could throw 404 you'll need to prove one-by-one if they are working to find the root cause(s).

First I'd try the bucket itself, use `<s3-bucket-url>/index.html` and see if the file (in this case *index.html* ) exists.

Second the cloudfront, I'll assume the cloudfront distribution is configured correctly (i.e. `/` path redirects to `/index.html`). Also, every time you edit the bucket files, create an [invalidation to speed up propagation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html).

Third, you'll need to tell your users to constantly hard reload the page, or use incognito, specially if your site is in constant development.